# Datafactory : forloop not running in parallel

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am using data factory foreach activity . however the sub-sequence activity are running in sequence . Even issequence is not check . Let's have a look on the following screen. 
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: were you able to fix or find what was the reason ?

Answer (score 0):

What is that your sub activity doing ? I did tried a very simple test and I think it is working as expected . Please share more info and I will like to investigate further in this .

This is what i tried .

Created a pipeline with array as a variable , just add four elements to that and in the foreach loop printed the value using the Set Variable activity . I added a wait activity to make it more visible . I set the sequential as false and batch count as 2 . 
This is what i see the , the set variable is grouped together and the value for the SV activity is not in order , very much on the expected lines .

[image]

Now when i set the seqiuential = true , i see that only one value is picked at a time .
[image]

Comment: the subactivity in the forloop is a "ExecutePipeline" activity

Comment: When you do a trigger run it should show you that is not working sequentially , but in the debug mode it always run in sequential mode .

Comment: ammm.. seems not. I have another similar data factory it.s parallel even in debug

Comment: Strange though ... I was able to  see the difference between the trigger run and debug mode with the Execute pipeline activity  .

Talking about the the other pipeline which you mentioned , i have tested this a simple Set Variable and it works just the same in debug and trigger mode .